# MySQL REPLACE in UPDATE does not work properly

Tags: mysql

The following query:

```
select replace(`Abilities`, 'export_import', 'auto') from fl_account_types;
```

gives me 'auto,listings' correct replacement from `Abilities` column. However, when I execute:

```
update fl_account_types set `Abilities` = replace(`Abilities`, 'export_import', 'autos');
```

MySQL just omits 'export_import' string and replaces `Abilities` with 'listings' string.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Abilities was of type SET and I was trying to replace with a value which was not listed in a definition of it. But I still do not understand why select replace works well and why MySQL do not throw an error.